# enable compression on a server

Tags: compression, gzip, deflate

I'm running the page speed test on google and it is telling me that i need to enable compression on my server.

Can you please provide me information on how to enable compression on my server?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you google "enable compression on [your server here]"?

Comment: What web server are you using? Perhaps http://webmasters.stackexchange.com would be a better forum to get an answer